# Unable to connect to internet with VirtualBox using bridged adapter?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

Earlier, I was using multiple instances of Virtual Machines running Linux Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. They were working fine, with internet connectivity, etc. However, I then created a new Virtual Machine with the same settings, and now all of a sudden, all three of my virtual machines cannot connect to the internet. Currently, the network settings are at Bridged Adapter. The internet DOES work when I use NAT, but I need to use the Bridged Adapter setting for the project I am working on.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling virtualbox, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling the VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver, as well as turning off and turning on my host computer. Now I am completely out of ideas and it has been putting my work to a standstill. If you have any ideas on how to fix this problem, it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use Bridged?  In the past (before the NAT option was available) I found almost randomly that Bridged would not work (or just stop working) and I've have to switch to something else.

Comment: @Bernmeister yes that's exactly what's happening! I want to use Bridged because it provides me two different IP addresses on the two machines, which is what I need. If there is an alternative (more reliable) method to doing so, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Based on my reading of https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged, I don't see where Bridged will give you more than one IP address.  Also, I've checked a VM I have (Ubuntu server 12.04) running under VirtualBox 4.3.12 and it's using Bridged and has one IP address which is accessible by all other physical/virtual machines on my LAN.  Where did you read about two IP addresses?  I assumed you would need two (virtual) adapters.

Comment: @Bernmeister yes, I was using two virtual machines to get unique ip addresses for each one. Anyways, my problem has been fixed now, it was not a fault on my end but rather on our work's network. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Voting to close because problem was elsewhere and solved. Question has no use to others.

Comment: Reviewers: the answer clearly states that this problem had a completely unreproducible cause - will not help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem was not with my computer, but with the network I was working with at work. Sorry for the confusion, but after people fixed the screwy network, it solved my issue. Thanks!